# C Programming: Using format specifiers

Tags: c, char, printf

In the C language, The answer of

```
char c='61'; 
printf ("%d", c);
```

is 49. The answer of

```
char c='61'; 
printf ("%c", c);
```

is 1. The answer of

```
char c=61; 
printf ("%d", c);
```

is 61. The answer of

```
char c=61; 
printf ("%c", c);
```

is `=`. How is this happening exactly?

Comment: You are missing `c=061;` and `c=0x61;` to complete the set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first two cases,

```
 char c='61';
```

have implementation-defined behaviour and not standard complaint. Quoting `C11`, chapter 6.4.5/P10

> *An integer character constant has type int. The value of an integer character constant containing a single character that maps to a single-byte execution character is the numerical value of the representation of the mapped character interpreted as an integer. **The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g., `'ab'`), or containing a character or escape sequence that does not map to a single-byte execution character, is implementation-defined.**[....]*

It may not be a valid behaviour on your environment. Your compiler might have issued a warning there. Something like

```
warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
     char c='61';
            ^~~~
warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
```

In other two cases, read about [most common character encoding, ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/).

- When you print the integer value using `%d`, it prints the value `61`.
- When you print the character representation of integer value 61 using `%c`, decimal value of `61` is for the ASCII character `=`. That gets printed.

Comment: Small correction: First 2 cases are not invalid, but simply implementation defined (C17 draft §6.4.5 p10). It's still a good idea to avoid using them.

Comment: @user694733 Added the reference.